# How running old Tensorflow 1.x / tf1.x code?

Tags: tensorflow

Sometimes, I'm facing problem running old tensorflow 1.x code.

What are the strategies?

Answer (score 0):

I've found mainly 3 strategies, ordered by preference:

1. Using Colab to run tf1 code. It seems that only tf2 is supported by Colab, but that's not true, you still can use pip to uninstall tf2 and install a specific version of tf1. `!yes|pip uninstall tensorflow`, `!pip install tensorflow==1.15.5` Maybe you should install other dependencies. So use `!pip install -r requirements.txt` Attention! You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.
2. Using virtual environment with Anaconda or plain Python Virtual Environment (Virtualenv) to run tf1 code
3. Migrate your code from tf1 to tf2 using conversion script (tf_upgrade_v2) and manual edition. To do that, please check https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate?hl=en Could be a lot of work, but it's justified if you want to maintain and develop the code.

Comment: As an update:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.5 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.15.0rc0) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.5

Comment: uninstall python3 and install python2

Answer (score 0):

Collab doesn't support tensorflow 1.x because it uses by default python 3
you will need to install python 2 or 3.6 and it's pip and do what you want
this will work fine in collab.

```
!apt-get install python2

!curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
!python2 get-pip.py


!python2 -m pip install tensorflow==1.3.0
!python2 -m pip install tflearn==0.3.2
```